# Trouble with ribbons using divs - navigation menu

Tags: css, html, ribbon, nav

I'm using this HTML:

```
<div id="navleft"></div>
<nav id="nav">
</nav>
<div id="navright"></div>
```

And this CSS:

```
#navleft {
background:url('./images/navleft.png');
height:48px;
width:11px;
float:left;
position:absolute;
margin-left:-13px;
}

#navright {
background:url('./images/navright.png');
height:48px;
width:11px;
float:right;
margin-right:-13px;
}

#nav {
background:url('./images/navbg.png') repeat-x;
height:48px;
width:100%;
float:left;
position:relative;
}
```

The problem is the left/right images won't attach to the main ribbon.

I've tried messing with positions, displays, and margins but the closest I've got to my goal has been 1 pixel of white in between them (the code above).

[Visual example](http://i48.tinypic.com/fjhvmt.png)

Can anyone explain why this is happening and/or offer a solution?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Try using Inspector to check what is that 1px white space which blocking is it to join to `#nav`.

Comment: Inspector seems to be showing that it's [part of the sides](http://i48.tinypic.com/fjhvmt.png) @AspiringAqib

Comment: You are using Normalized CSS?

Comment: Not that I know of, should I be?

Answer (score 0):

try this

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hQrSM/8/)

```
   #navleft {
background:url('http://placehold.it/48x48') ;
float:left;
height:48px;
width:48px;
}

#navright {
background:url('http://placehold.it/48x48') ;
height:48px;
float:left;
width:48px;
}

#nav {
background:url('http://placehold.it/75x48') repeat-x;
height:48px;
width:70%;
float:left;
}
```

adjust the height and width accordingly,

Comment: thanks for the response, result of this [here](http://i47.tinypic.com/245km4l.png)